# Cannot able to get latlong on selected place

Tags: android

I am using google places SDK and when I try to get place info when selected I can able to get name and id but I cannot get latlng and etc

```
 fragments[1].setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i("asd", "Place: " + place.getLatLng().latitude + ", " + place.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i("asd", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

### My logcat

```
I/asd: Place: Place{address=null, addressComponents=null, attributions=[], id=ChIJO3svnEReUjoR38xr0NFxtiU, latLng=null, name=Vels University, openingHours=null, phoneNumber=null, photoMetadatas=null, plusCode=null, priceLevel=null, rating=null, types=null, userRatingsTotal=null, viewport=null, websiteUri=null}, ChIJO3svnEReUjoR38xr0NFxtiU
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   fragments[1].setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));
```

I want to add Place .field.Lat_LNG attribute like so above

as per 
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/place-details